# Can I redirect another webpage to my webpage from htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website let it's url be a `http://abcd.com`.

Let I have another domain name `http://nirdosh.com`. I didnot get any space for this domain.

How can I redirect `nirdosh.com` to `abcd.com` using htaccess or any other way.

Thanks